# Проблема со спрайтами В питоне(pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

столкнулся с проблемой, есть программа, где ездит машинка(с помощью стрелок ), подъезжает к спрайту, и при нажатии на пробел около спрайта он должен пропасть и должен воспроизвестись соответственный звук. Спрайты, которые нужно взять, появляются раз в секунду. Проблема заключается в том, что на экране спрайт подразумевается и берется, при нажатии пробела, но его не видно)[image]  На изображении на самом деле больше 40 cпрайтов(тракторов)При появлении нового спрайта старый удаляется, но продолжает функционировать))) Помогите пожалуйста) 
Все используемые файлы(за исключением модуля pygame) и файл с программой в архиве здесь - `https://yadi.sk/d/srMDGjW9Xg6Jlg`
Все звуки пробные, потом заменю на подходящие.
Заранее всем спасибо) Надеюсь хоть кто ни будь откликнется(

Comment: Архив не полный: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "АНИМАЦИОННАЯ ИГРА 2.py", line 20, in <module>
    imageCarRight = pygame.image.load('carR.gif')
pygame.error: Couldn't open carR.gif

Comment: carU.gif и carD.gif там тоже нет

Comment: извиняюсь, забыл совсем, сейчас добавлю

Comment: Вот правильная ссылка, там файл с программой другой

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/srMDGjW9Xg6Jlg

Comment: Я исправил. Код вообще надо переделывать в целом, но он теперь хотя бы работает :)  Смотрите ниже мой ответ с кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно итерировались по "еде", я исправил цикл почти в конце программы и стало показывать:

```
import pygame, sys, time, random 
from pygame.locals import *

# Установка pygame
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Настройка окна
WINDOWWIDTH = 1000
WINDOWHEIGHT = 1000
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Спрайты и звуки')

# Настройка цвета
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)

# Создание структур данных блока
car = pygame.Rect(500, 300, 40, 40)

imageCarLeft = pygame.image.load('carL.gif')
carLStretchedImage = pygame.transform.scale(imageCarLeft, (40, 40))
foodImage = pygame.image.load('90695.jpg')
foodCounter = 0
NEWFOOD = 40
FOODSIZE = 20
foods = []
for i in range(20):
    foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 20, 20))

# создание переменных клавиатуры
moveLeft = False
moveRight = False
moveUp = False
moveDown = False

MOVESPEED = 6

#Настройка музыки
avaria = pygame.mixer.Sound('avaria.wav')
benzin = pygame.mixer.Sound('benzin.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.load('dvigatel.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
musicPlaying = True

# Запуск игрового цикла
while True:
    # проверка событий
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #Изменение переменных клавиатуры
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                moveRight = False
                moveLeft = True

            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True

            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                moveDown = False
                moveUp = True

            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w:
                moveUp = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s:
                moveDown = False
            if event.key == K_x:
                car.top = random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - car.height)
                car.left = random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - car.width)
            if event.key == K_m:
                if music.playing:
                    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
                else:
                    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)
                musicPlaying = not musicPlaying

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            foods.append(pygame.Rect(event.pos[0] - 10, event.pos[1] - 10, 20, 20))

    foodCounter += 1
    if foodCounter >= NEWFOOD:
        # Добавление новой "еды"
        foodCounter = 0
        foods.append(pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH - 20), random.randint(0, WINDOWHEIGHT - 20), 20, 20))

    #Создание белого фона
    windowSurface.fill(WHITE)

    #Перемещение игрока
    if moveDown and car.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
        car.top += MOVESPEED
    if moveUp and car.top > 0:
        car.top -= MOVESPEED
    if moveLeft and car.left > 0:
        car.left -= MOVESPEED
    if moveRight and car.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
        car.right += MOVESPEED
    if moveDown and car.bottom == WINDOWHEIGHT:
        avaria.play
    if moveUp and car.top == 0:
        avaria.play
    if moveLeft and car.left == 0:
        avaria.play
    if moveRight and car.right == WINDOWWIDTH:
        avaria.play


    windowSurface.blit(carLStretchedImage, car)
    # Проверка, не пересекся ли игрок с блоками "еды".
    for food in foods[:]:
        if car.colliderect(food) and event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
                foods.remove(food)
                if musicPlaying:
                    benzin.play()

    # ----> Исправил этот цикл <----             
    for food in foods:
        windowSurface.blit(foodImage, food)

    # Вывод окна на  экран
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40 )
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!